# Updating a top level list from a subsite

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list

I have a contracts list on the top level site because it needs to be accessed by multiple subsites, however one of the subsites has a list that gathers some pieces of information that I need to push to that top level list as a new item.

In SPDesigner, I can create a workflow to update an item in a list on the same site, but not a different site (top or otherwise).

Can anyone tell me how I can update or add a new item on a top level site list from a subsite?

Answer (score 1):

You can try SharePoint 2010 ECMA script which could be triggered from within a CEWP (but not automatically upon insert!). You need to make sure you get a reference to the List in the Top-Level site, not on the context Web using something like :

```
currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.sitecoll = currentcontext.get_site();  //-> Gets Top level site collection
currentcontext.load(this.sitecoll);
```

See example for update at the following locations:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185011